# Issue with rock paper scissors Discord.js command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying to implement a rock paper scissors command in to a Discord bot and this the relevant part of my code.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'rps',
description: "plays a game of rock paper scissors",
execute(message, args){


let userResponse = args.slice(1).join(" ");
JSON.stringify(userResponse);
if(userResponse != 'R' || 'P' || 'S' || 'r' || 'p' || 's') return message.channel.send(':x: Please provide a proper response. \n**Options:** `R` (rock), `P` (paper), `S` (scissors)')
if(!userResponse) return message.channel.send(':x: Please provide a proper response. \n**Options:** `R` (rock), `P` (paper), `S` (scissors)');
```

However, when I perform the command (let's say I write **lm!rps R**) the bot just tells me to provide a proper response, with no info given in console.

If you can help with this, I'd appreciate it!
-flameless

Comment: What is the actual value of the `userResponse` variable?

Comment: @mousetail actual value is whatever the user writes after **lm!rps** (at least that what it is supposed to be)

Comment: OK, but can you print it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @mousetail , the value the user is **supposed** to input is either _R, P, S, r, p, s_

Comment: Yes, but what is the actual value? It is clearly *not* any of those values, hence the error

Comment: My bad @mousetail, the value I full command I am inputting is **lm!rps R** and, in this case, the value the variable should take is **R**

Comment: @mousetail when I print the value, everything seems to be right and _userResponse =  R_ but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't work:

```
userResponse != 'R' || 'P' || 'S' || 'r' || 'p' || 's'
```

This will evalutae as `(userResponse != 'R') || 'p' || ...`

`'p'` as a non-empty string is considered truthy, so the value for the entire expression will be truthy, so the condition is always true.

A better option to check if the user response is any correct letter is `['R', 'P', 'S', ...].indexOf(userResponse)==-1`. Another option would be `userResponse != 'R' && userResponse != 'P' && ...`